# Using dicts or making classes? which is faster?

Tags: python, dictionary

I get a multi level dict object, which I have to process. By multi level I mean the top level dict has some keys with dicts as value.

e.g.

```
{'l1key1' : 'value1'
 'l1key2' : {
             'l2key1': 'something'
             'l2key2': {
                        'l3key1': 'something' 
                        'l3key2': 'something else'
                       }
            }
 'l1key3' : 'some other value'
}
```

The  actual dict is huge. It has some 10+ keys and 4 levels. Sometimes some optional keys might be missing.

I made classes to keep the code organized.
e.g

```
Class Level3():
    def __init__(self, l3dict):
        if not l3dict:
            self.exists = False
        else:
            self.exists = True
            self.l3key1 = l3dict.get('l3key1') 
            self.l3key2 = l3dict.get('l3key2')

Class Level2():
    def __init__(self, l2dict):
        if not l2dict:
            self.exists = False
        else:
            self.exists = True
            self.l2key1 = l2dict.get('l2key1') 
            self.l2key2 = Level3(l3dict.get('l2key2'))

Class Level1():
    def __init__(self, mydict):
            self.l1key1 = mydict.get('l1key1') 
            self.l1key2 = Level2(mydict.get('l1key2'))
            self.l1key3 = mydict.get('l1key3')


#usage
mydict = json.loads(thejson)     #the json I am getting as input
myobject = Level1(mydict)
```

My question is should I use the dict directly in my script instead of making the classes?

Having low execution time is important. Will initializing the classes from the dict make it slow?

Edit:: I timed it. the initialization of the class takes 80 microseconds on average, The application has to complete all the processing within 250 milliseconds. I will now have to see time taken by the processing to determine if I can afford the 80 microseconds.

Thankyou for the answers. I will also be using Cython for processing the data.

Comment: Why are people afraid of strongly typed models?

Comment: how many millions of accesses per millisecond are you going to make to this data? I mean I would just make sure it is maintainable.

Comment: The question is: What advantage do you gain by wrapping it in classes? How do you handle dictionaries of arbitrary depth?

Comment: This is not going to help - you are still using multi-level dicts, just that you have added some syntax sugar on top. You need to work with objects and properties. Creating things does not affect execution time - what affects it is the _operations_ you are doing. You can only optimize loops so unless you show that part of your code, wrapping dictionaries into classes is just unnecessary.

Comment: If you're seriously concerned about performance you ought to put it in a database.

Comment: @akonsu The average expected access rate is around 50/second

Comment: @Hyperboreus This is for OpenRTB protocol. I know the maximum depth but some keys are optional and might be missing. The advantage is keeping things organised e.g I might have to calculate some values from the given values, so having functions relevent to level3 in the level3 class

Comment: you should not use a class to only encapsulate data.  you should use a class if you wish to also encapsulate behaviors or methods

Comment: If you're asking if repeatedly creating multiple objects is costly in Python, then the answer is "yes". CPython objects have a very heavy and slow implementation when you compare them to C structs. In general if you want speed, you want to use as little objects as possible or just avoid CPython implementation altogether and go for something faster.

Comment: @WaleedKhan - how do you think it will be stored when it is accessed from a database? Storing things as objects in RAM is almost always faster than fetching from a database.

Comment: Nobody has yet said that Python objects are implemented as dictionaries anyway. This isn't C, the structs aren't compiled. It's all dynamic.

Comment: @Joe very good point. :) OP should just remember that making any instance object in CPython, especially repeatedly, is quite costly. I would take a look at pypy.org (faster alternative implementation of Python) and cython.org (C extensions modules) for ideas on making your code truly fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get this question answered, using just using the dicts that you've already set up would be faster. Creating objects, even trivial ones, in CPython is extremely costly as I've stated in the comments.